# Run and log the output of 'ping' in a loop in a Python script

Tags: python, while-loop, io

i wrote a simple agaent in python that all it dose is just cheacks for the internet connection.
When he finds out that ther is no connection he writes a log file to a text the hour and date and then just exit the program.

I want it to keep testing if there is a connection even if there is not how can i do this ? without the program exit

this is the code:

```
import os
import time
def Main():

    ping =os.system('ping -n 1 -l 1000 8.8.8.8 ')
    while ping ==0:
        time.sleep(4)
        ping = os.system('ping -n 1 -l 1000 8.8.8.8 ')
        if ping ==1:
            print 'no connection'
            CT =time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%y")
            alert=' No Connection'
            f = open('logfile.txt','a+')
            f.write('\n'+CT)
            f.write(alert)
            f.close()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Thanx a lot.

Comment: Note that your `while` loop won't run if the first `ping` command fails. So if that happens nothing will get written to your logfile.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `Main` call in an *infinite loop*?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        Main() 
        time.sleep(1) # optional, as Main already contains a sleep time
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should set you on your way.  Just substitute the host with that of your choosing in the call to the `LogPing` object.

Check out the comments inline and please ask me if you have any questions.

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import shlex
import subprocess
from time import sleep



class LogPing:

    def __init__(self, host, count=1, timeout_seconds=10, logfile="ping_log.txt"):
        self.host = host
        self.count = count
        self.timeout_seconds = timeout_seconds
        self.logfile = logfile

        self.output_blackhole = open(os.devnull, 'wb')


    def _command(self):
        command_string = "ping -c {count} -t {timeout} {host}".format(
                count=self.count, 
                timeout=self.timeout_seconds,
                host=self.host
            )

        try: 
            # we don't actually care about the output, just the return code, 
            # so trash the output. result == 0 on success
            result = subprocess.check_call(
                    shlex.split(command_string), 
                    stdout=self.output_blackhole, 
                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
                )
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            # if here, that means that the host couldn't be reached for some reason.
            result = -1

        return result

    def run(self):
        ping_command_result = self._command()

        if ping_command_result == 0:
            status = "OK"
        else:
            status = "NOK"

        # The time won't be exact, but close enough
        message = "{status} : {time} : {host}\n".format(
                status=status, 
                time=datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%T"), 
                host=self.host
            )

        # open file in a context manager for writing, creating if not exists
        # using a+ so that we append to the end of the last line.
        with open(self.logfile, 'a+') as f:
            f.write(message)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        ping_instance = LogPing("example.org").run()
        sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand yous correctly this will do its job:

```
import os
import time

def Main():

    while True:
        ping = os.system('ping -n 1 -l 1000 8.8.8.8 ')
        if ping:
            print 'no connection'
            CT =time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%y")
            alert=' No Connection'
            with open('logfile.txt','a+') as f:
                f.write('\n'+CT)
                f.write(alert)

        time.sleep(4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: I omitted function call, fixed.